# Fetch last month data from firebase Php

Tags: php, laravel

I want to fetch the count of last month names data from database using php.

I am storing the data field like below:

```
{
  "2019-04-11": [
    "alex",
    "jhon",
    "vinu"
  ],
  "2019-04-12": [
    "Mario",
    "pech"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your efforts/snippets you tried until now?

Comment: What queries did you try and what error do they give them? What do you think you are doing wrong? Show us that at least you tried...

Comment: I am not tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, next approach may help.

- Decode your `JSON` data to an array using [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). The result will be an array with dates as keys and names as values.
- Loop throw this array, convert the key to date with  [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), compare dates and count the names:

PHP:

```
<?php

# JSON
$json = '
    {
    "2019-04-11": [
        "alex",
        "jhon",
        "vinu"
    ],
    "2019-04-12": [
        "Mario",
        "pech"
    ]
    }
';
$data = json_decode($json, true);

# Count names
$count = 0;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $key);
    if ($date->format('Y-m') == '2019-04') {
        $count += count($value);    
    }
}

# Output
echo 'Count: '.$count;  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

First divide your key-value pair into two array , using  `array_divide()`

Below code will return you month

```
explode('-',array_divide($arr)[0][0])[1]
```

explode take only string so, it placed in at this place

```
array_divide($arr)[0][0]
```

explode will divide in array from -, and month is place at second place means at 1 index.

and it will return count

`count(array_divide($arr)[1][0])`

Consider `$arr` equal to your variable.

Hope this helps :)